# How do I change the HTML response into JSON for all requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring boot.

I'd like to know how do I enforce all response from HTML format into JSON? Take the belown sign-in failure request for example.

Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <title>Please sign in</title>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <p>
                        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i got the html response from the spring boot by using postman. nothing to do with spring boot?

Comment: Sorry !! My Bad. I thought you want to sent JSON from page itself.